# Is there a colors.xml equivalent for IOS storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode

Right now I am setting all my colors by hand when editing in the storyboard. This is rather unfortunate as any future changes to hex codes will mean that I need to manually change each colored element.

I was wondering if there was a way to abstract all color configurations into a `colors.xml` android-esque file for IOS

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only available in iOS 11 and later, but you can make a color set in your `.xcassets` file and reference that color in your storyboards and your code, as described in [this blog post](https://blog.zeplin.io/asset-catalog-colors-on-xcode-9-c4fdccc0381a)

Comment: It's a JSON file where you can define color constants to use throughout your app

Comment: And I am assuming anything prior to IOS 11 I have to do by hand then?

Comment: Unfortunately so, as far as I know :/ This feels like something that should've been gotten around to *far* sooner

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like the link is broken